# IOTAs sent to the seed instead of an address

Tags: seed, balances, token

I saw someone sent IOTAs to the seed!

IOTAs sent to seed instead of address will be stuck forever. Until some seed randomly creates that as an address. Is it possible?

Is there any way to retrieve them?

---

**EDIT**

GUI wallet does not allow to send to the address with a checksum. So, it's not possible to send to a seed via GUI wallet. But I guess its possible via API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send funds to the wrong address and the transaction is confirmed: there is no way to get your funds back.

If the transaction is not confirmed yet,  you can try to double spend and hope that the second transaction will be confirmed before the wrong one. (it will expose your key to an attacker... But anyway your funds will be lost if you do nothing)

Comment: true. But is it possible that same address (which is actually seed) will be generated someday by any seed?

Comment: In theory yes, it's possible (there is no code to prevent that). In practice: the probality for this event to occurs is 0.

Answer (score -3):

Adresses have 90 characters.
Seeds have 81 characters.

So no way, you did see that I am sorry.

Comment: An address has 81 char + 9 char checksum. **Yes, It's not possible to send  to only address (without checksum) from the GUI wallet.** But I guess its possible to send to the address without checksum.

Comment: Hello Foxxer, while your answer seems correct—if a bit superficial—it would benefit a lot from an explanation to why that difference is that important.